# A good icon for kcharselect

Tags: 20.04, icons, character-set

In the K menu, **kcharselect** doesn't have an icon.  Can anyone suggest a good one (at the appropriate size, of course)?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application desktop file (`/usr/share/applications/org.kde.kcharselect.desktop`) define the Icon as `accessories-character-map`.
So you can find such icons on the local filesystem using `dpkg -S accessories-character-map.{svg,png}` to determine theme names with this icon.
The most reliable way is to use default icon set named Breeze or Oxygen.

Other way is to get icon from the [source code repository](https://salsa.debian.org/qt-kde-team/kde/kcharselect):

| 64x64 | 128x128 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: 64x64] | [image: 128x128] |

and place one of them in `~/.local/share/icons/`.